# Why does my PC have a routing table?

Tags: windows-7, routing

I've just done a `route print` command in the command prompt and it displayed an "IPv4 Route Table". Why does my computer have an IPv4 Route Table?

Also there's a column called "Metric" what does this mean?

Answer (score 9):

Every computer that wants to take part in IP communication should have a routing table. It has to know where to send which packets.

Usually the table will be short and simple as there is little to route. The most important entry will be the default entry (with `0.0.0.0` destination), which should tell that the packet should be directed to your default gateway.

About the **Metric** parameter:

> Specifies an integer cost metric (ranging from 1 to 9999) for the route, which is used when choosing among multiple routes in the routing table that most closely match the destination address of a packet being forwarded. The route with the lowest metric is chosen. The metric can reflect the number of hops, the speed of the path, path reliability, path throughput, or administrative properties.

[Source](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/route.mspx?mfr=true)